# .done() callback when using custom jQuery Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, deferred, custom-function

I'm using the following functions in order to animate slides just like `slideUp()` or `slideDown()`:

```
(function($) {    
    jQuery.fn.slideLeftHide = function(speed, callback) {
      this.animate({
        width: "hide",
        paddingLeft: "hide",
        paddingRight: "hide",
        marginLeft: "hide",
        marginRight: "hide"
      }, speed, callback);
    }

    jQuery.fn.slideLeftShow = function(speed, callback) {
      this.animate({
        width: "show",
        paddingLeft: "show",
        paddingRight: "show",
        marginLeft: "show",
        marginRight: "show"
      }, speed, callback);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The thing is, that i want to call a function **only once** after the animation ends.
 I tried doing this by:

```
$(".item").slideLeftHide(function() {
    $(this).remove();

}).done(function() {
    $(".tab").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('data-status', 'success');
    });
});
```

When I execute this code, I get an error message saying `Cannot read property 'done' of undefined`. The same happens with `.then()` instead of `.done()`.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not returning promise so can't use done/then, Use  the callback which you passing i.e. `$(".item").slideLeftHide(function() {
    $(this).remove();
$(".tab").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('data-status', 'success');
    });
})`

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function ($) {
    function slideLeftBinder(action) {
        return function () {
            var i = 0,
                speed = ((Number(arguments[i]) === parseFloat(arguments[i]) && !isNaN(arguments[i])) || undefined) && arguments[i++],
                callback = (typeof arguments[i] === 'function' || undefined) && arguments[i++],
                self = this;

            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                var completed = 0;

                self.animate({
                    width: action,
                    paddingLeft: action,
                    paddingRight: action,
                    marginLeft: action,
                    marginRight: action
                }, {
                    duration: speed,
                    complete: callback,
                    always: function() {
                        if (self.length === ++completed) {
                            resolve(self);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    }

    jQuery.fn.slideLeftHide = slideLeftBinder('hide');
    jQuery.fn.slideLeftShow = slideLeftBinder('show');
})(jQuery);
```

Use it like this:

```js
$(".item")
    .slideLeftHide(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    })
    .then(function(selector) {
        console.log('selector: ', selector);
        $(".tab").attr('data-status', 'success');
    });
```

Comment: @ItayGanor Of course is not a function! `.then` is not a method from `$().animate`. You want the `.done()` method instead, as you mentioned!

Here is a [list of the methods and properties](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) you can use

Comment: When using `done()` the error is same: `$(...).slideLeftHide(...).done is not a function`.

Comment: @ItayGanor I'm sorry I was confused, as you said, `.done` is not a method, its an option that can be passed as an argument inside `$().animate` method. I'll reformulate my answer!

Comment: @ItayGanor Updated. I'm sorry for the confusion I initially made, I don't work with jQuery for a while!